# Two-photon processes diagrams in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Along my document, I have to display repeatedly, various figures containing diagrams as the included in the image:
[image]

I am wondering which would be an effective approach to deal with this need within a latex document? I must be able of change the states, and also the sense of the transition. Any sugestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: TeXample: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/fluor-energy-levels/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use next as starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\coordinate (dash) at (0,0);
\coordinate[below=3cm of dash] (psii);
\coordinate[below=1.5cm of psii] (psif);

\draw[dashed, thick] (dash)--++(0:5cm);
\draw[thick] (psii)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_i\rangle$};
\draw[thick] (psif)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_f\rangle$};;

\draw[->] ([xshift=1cm]psii) -- ([xshift=1cm]dash) node[left, midway] (hwi) {$\hslash\omega_I$};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=3cm]psif) -- ([xshift=3cm]dash) coordinate(aux);
\path (aux|-hwi) node[right] {{$\hslash\omega_S$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Update: How to embed `tikzpicture` in latex document*

You can insert any `tikzpicture` where you want inside a `.tex` document. It's considered like any other character. Next you'll find two examples, the first one creates a new paragraph and centers figure inside. The second one uses a floating `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

{\par\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\coordinate (dash) at (0,0);
\coordinate[below=3cm of dash] (psii);
\coordinate[below=1.5cm of psii] (psif);

\draw[dashed, thick] (dash)--++(0:5cm);
\draw[thick] (psii)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_i\rangle$};
\draw[thick] (psif)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_f\rangle$};;

\draw[->] ([xshift=1cm]psii) -- ([xshift=1cm]dash) node[left, midway] (hwi) {$\hslash\omega_I$};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=3cm]psif) -- ([xshift=3cm]dash) coordinate(aux);
\path (aux|-hwi) node[right] {{$\hslash\omega_S$}};
\end{tikzpicture}\par}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
\coordinate (dash) at (0,0);
\coordinate[below=3cm of dash] (psii);
\coordinate[below=1.5cm of psii] (psif);

\draw[dashed, thick] (dash)--++(0:5cm);
\draw[thick] (psii)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_i\rangle$};
\draw[thick] (psif)--++(0:5cm) node[right]{$|\psi_f\rangle$};;

\draw[->] ([xshift=1cm]psii) -- ([xshift=1cm]dash) node[left, midway] (hwi) {$\hslash\omega_I$};
\draw[<-] ([xshift=3cm]psif) -- ([xshift=3cm]dash) coordinate(aux);
\path (aux|-hwi) node[right] {{$\hslash\omega_S$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two photon processes diagram}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. This approach can be embedded directly in a latex document?

Comment: @user3116936: Yes. An independent `tikzpicture` environment is managed as any other character but you can also include into a floating `figure`. An example: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\usepackage{amssymb}\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}\begin{document} The text you want .... \begin{ikzpicture}....\end{tikzpicture} Some more text \end{document}`

Comment: When I compile the merged code, as above,  using pdflatex, I get the error "undefined control sequence \usetikzlibrary", any idea?

Comment: @user3116936 Did you use `\usepackage{tikz}` before `usetikzlibrary`?

Comment: Yes, I did, even more, without the "\usetikzlibrary{pos‌​itioning,arrows}" the document compiles properly.

Comment: @user3116936 I don't understand what you say. I've updated the answer, try my code and explain me what happens with it on your system.

Comment: I tried and the code works well, thanks a lot.